# Access a service from one container to other

Tags: php, mysql, bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm following a docker web application setup tutorial from [here](http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html). As described in the `docker-compose.yml` file the `MySQL` container is linked to the app and it is accessible via both `index.php` and `phpMyAdmin`. No problem so far.

When I opened an interactive shell for my application using `docker exec -it container-id bash` and tried to access the `MySQL` service but I couldn't. What I'm I missing here?

**Edit1:** When I type `MySQL`, I get `bash: mysql: command not found`.

**Edit2:** Output of `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
1643f0ba5637        dockertutorial_php      "docker-php-entryp..."   9 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        9000/tcp               dockertutorial_php_1
610f2c8bf4c4        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     9 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   dockertutorial_phpmyadmin_1
29c552da473b        mysql:latest            "docker-entrypoint..."   10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds        3306/tcp               dockertutorial_mysql_1
```

**Edit3:** Perhaps I should have started with this. I apologise for all the confusion caused/would cause (Especially to @Jay Blanchard & @mkasberg). I want to run a bash script inside the nginx container which creates a MySQL database. It works if I have installed MySQL in the nginx container but not if it is a separate container. Is it possible to achieve with the current approach? If not how should I correct it?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the container have the mysql server as an entry in its hosts file? can you ping the mysql container from the linked container? Is the mysql server set up to allow access from other machines?

Comment: `mysql -u *name* -p`?

Comment: How did you try to access it and what problem did you have?

Comment: @JimL Sorry, I'm not sure how to do it. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've updated with error message.

Comment: What are you using for `container-id` in the command `docker exec -it container-id bash`?

Comment: @mkasberg It is the container id: `1643f0ba5637` which I found when I did `docker ps`.

Comment: Can you add the output from `docker ps -a`? You may also want to try the name of the container, rather than the ID

Comment: Yes, but which container is that ID for? Which one of the services from `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: It is `nginx` container!!!

Comment: Are you running MySQL in the NGINX container? If you followed the tutorial you should have more than one container. Please post the output of `docker ps -a`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Updated with output of `docker ps`

Comment: `docker exec -it dockertutorial_mysql_1 /bin/bash`

Comment: Why use a bash script in the NGINX container when you could use PHP to execute table creation commands?

Comment: It's more complicated than I've explained in the question. The bash script is an installation procedure depending on user's requirement. It actually clones a repository depending on user's choice which will be done after the mysql database & tables are created.

Comment: Why does it need to be run from the NGINX container?

Comment: Agreed - why does it need to be run from the `nginx` container? Also, can you not just `yum install mysql` at the top of your bash script?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @mkasberg Yes I could do that and it worked. If that's the case then I don't need a separate container running `MySQL`. So I just wanted to know if at all it is possible to interact with a service running in another container?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Agreed, its my bad!!!

Comment: If you know the remote server IP then you can `mysql -u -p -h REMOTE_SERVER_IP DB_NAME` The remote IP in this case *might* be the IP of the computer, not the internal IP of the MySQL Docker container. I've never tried this, so I will be interested to know if it works.

Comment: Yes, of course you can interact with a service running in another container. For example, to access MySQL from your nginx container, first install MySQL: (inside nginx container) `apt-get install mysql`. After that, connect. The hostname is the same as the service name in `docker-compose.yml`: (inside nginx container) `mysql -u root -p -h mysql`

Answer (score 1):

`mysql: command not found` means that the mysql client binary is not available in whichever container you're logged in to. I suspect you're running `docker exec` on a container other than the MySQL one. The binary would be there in the MySQL container. While those other containers *can* connect do MySQL, they *don't* have the MySQL command line application available (to keep image size small).

Make sure you're connecting to the MySQL container with your `docker exec` command and it should work. In fact, docker-compose provides a way for you to do this. With your services running (after doing `docker-compose up`), try this:

```
$ docker-compose exec mysql /bin/bash
```

That should get you to a bash prompt in the `mysql` container. Before, you were getting to a bash prompt in the `nginx` container. Which can't run `mysql` on the command line.

Comment: The `docker-compose.yml` links to the php container which in turn links to the `MySQL` container. Also I'm able to access MySQL via `index.php`. Could you please clarify for me?

Comment: I edited my answer to show the docker-compose command you need. You need to run bash in the mysql container if you want to connect to mysql like `mysql -u root -p -h localhost`.

Comment: While you can access MySQL via index.php from the `nginx` container, that is different than running the `mysql` client inside the `nginx` container. The `nginx` container can _only_ connect to MySQL through PHP (or another installed application). It does not have the `mysql` command line application installed.

Comment: Could you please update your code according to my latest update?